# Python script to automate saving satellite images for different combinations of lat longs

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, imagery, satellite

PS. : This is my first try at a GIS application. Please forgive if my question is pedantic.

I would like to get a series of satellite images all at the same scale centered around different points on the surface of the earth. The way I would like it to be done is to define a list of cities/towns say ["New York","London","Mumbai",...] and then generate randomly a set of lat/longs around each of these cities and save the satellite images hence gathered.

So for example the case of NY the lat/long of the center of the city is somewhere around (40.7N,74W). Then I randomly generate points close to it. I would finally like to get satellite images in and around NY city where each image would depict maybe a couple of blocks of the city. Further I would like to repeat this process for all the cities in my list.

Could you please guide me/ give me pointers how to do this and which satellite imagery database is more suitable?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Sandipan. I would recommend breaking this into two separate questions (i.e. different posts): 1) How to generate coordinates around a list of cities and 2) How to automatically download satellite imagery based on coords.

Comment: Do you have the various city x/y center coordinates, or are you looking for pointers how to generate those too?

Comment: Sorry I am travelling and hence unable to reply frequently. Assume I have the 1st part done i.e. I have the lat/long of the center known as a list and further I can generate a list of lat/longs for random points near the city center. Now given I know the resolution of the image required, how and from where to download images by python script.